# How to invoke Lambda function with Amplify using GraphQL API?

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I believe the default data source when creating GraphQL API is DynamoDB, I would like to set it to Lambda function instead.

**Is there a way to do this with Amplify?**

if not, **what is the workaround?**

I found this [AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html) online that states:

> we'll show you how to write a Lambda function that performs business logic based on the invocation of a GraphQL field operation.

but I couldn't use this with Amplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you can use this pattern described here to manually setup the correct templates and target a lambda that you setup with Amplify.

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#add-a-custom-resolver-that-targets-an-aws-lambda-function

Soon (or maybe by the time you read this, based on the status of this [PR](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/pull/1346)) you'll be able to annotate your GraphQL Schema with @function and have it wire up all that same stuff for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As @mwarger mention, you can annotate your gql schema with `@function`. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amplify-framework-adds-support-for-aws-lambda-functions-and-amazon-dynamodb-custom-indexes-in-graphql-schemas/

Comment: Here's the link to the latest docs https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/function/